# What are good examples of upgradable smartpy contracts using Proxy delegates or stored lambdas?

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy, upgrade

I'm trying to ensure my contract is upgradable and I learn best by looking at existing examples. Does anyone have any good examples to look at?

Here are some links to previous stackoverflow Q&A's discussuing smart contract updates:

1. [How to upgrade a smart contract](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/613/how-to-upgrade-a-smart-contract)
2. [Upgradeable Contracts: Proxy Delegate vs Stored Lambdas](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/3265/upgradeable-contracts-proxy-delegate-vs-stored-lambdas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stored lambdas approach:

It allows any packable value as a parameter and the method that computes the new value can be updated.

```
import smartpy as sp

class Upgradable(sp.Contract):
  def __init__(self, **kargs):
    self.init(**kargs)

  @sp.entry_point
  def calc(self, data):
    self.data.value = self.data.logic(data)

  @sp.entry_point
  def updateLogic(self, logic):
    self.data.logic = logic

@sp.add_test(name = "Upgradable")
def test():
  scenario = sp.test_scenario()
  scenario.h1("Upgradable")

  def logic1(data):
    t = sp.TRecord(x = sp.TNat, y = sp.TNat)
    unpacked = sp.unpack(data, t).open_some(message = "Cannot UNPACK")
    
    sp.result(unpacked.x + unpacked.y)
    
  def logic2(data):
    t = sp.TRecord(x = sp.TNat, y = sp.TNat, z = sp.TNat)
    unpacked = sp.unpack(data, t).open_some(message = "Cannot UNPACK")
    
    sp.result(unpacked.x + unpacked.y + unpacked.z)

  c1 = Upgradable(value = 0, logic = sp.build_lambda(logic1))
  scenario += c1

  # Use logic version 1
  scenario += c1.calc(sp.pack(sp.record(x = 1, y = 2)))

  # Update logic to version 2
  scenario += c1.updateLogic(sp.build_lambda(logic2))

  # Use logic version 2
  scenario += c1.calc(sp.pack(sp.record(x = 1, y = 2, z = 3)))
```

The proxy approach is also simple, it just points to the latest contract whenever a new one gets deployed.

Comment: awesome. thanks. 

if I were to want to support an arbitrary number  of operations, I suppose I would need to use a proxy delegate with a multipurpose entrypoint that can check the storage to see if a param.function is supported and call that function on the address associated with that function?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood the question, but yes, it is possible.

Comment: We are also working on an extension of the lazy entry point compilation for upgradable contracts. We expect to have something sometime in May.